# To convert float value to string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using two columns which have Date and float values, now I need to combine both the columns as a single string. For date I am able to convert it to string. But for the float values it is rounding up the decimal value which should not be the case.

For example my float value is 204.8 and date id 2014-11-11. Now when I combine as string it should result as '2014-11-11 204.8' But it is showing me as '2014-11-11 204' when I convert float value. I am using this query,

```
DECLARE @myDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @StandardCost INT
SET @myDateTime = '2011-12-24 00:00:00.000'
SET @StandardCost = 204.8
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @myDateTime, 120), 10)+ ' ' + CAST(@StandardCost AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

**Result: 2011-12-24 204**

Can anyone help me in getting exact float value with decimals as string.

Answer (score 5):

You have `@StandardCost` defined as an `int`. It will not hold the decimal portion. Change that to a `numeric` or some other datatype that will support decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to declare its as `FLOAT`, instead of `INT`

Then, you can try using [STR() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)

```
DECLARE @StandardCost FLOAT
SET @StandardCost = 204.8
SELECT STR(@StandardCost,10,1)
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Sean Lange said change the INT variable to a FLOAT

```
DECLARE @myDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @standardcost FLOAT;   -- <-------- Changed INT to FLOAT
SET @mydatetime = '2011-12-24 00:00:00.000';
SET @standardcost = 204.8;
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @mydatetime, 111), 10) + ' ' + CAST(@standardcost AS VARCHAR(MAX));
```

Comment: Hi I am using your code, I am getting the result as '2011-12-24 204.8' But I want it as '2011/12/24 204.8'. I mean in date there should slashes as i mentioned, can we get that?

Comment: You really should leave this kind of formatting stuff to the front end instead of doing it in sql. Take a look at CONVERT.

Comment: @Aparanjit, yes you can, just changed the convert code from 120 to 111